# javascript function not correctly returning an object

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm out of ideas.  I have a javascript function that returns an object, however the console keeps complaining about an Uncaught TypeError: cannot read properly 'lat' of undefined....  From console dumping i can see that everything is passing into the function correctly and i can see that the function is working properly.  The problem is with the return.  I'm not sure whats the problem, this seems fairly straight forward.  Side note, i'm working with the google maps/geocode api.

```
    function locate(val) {
        console.log(val);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': val}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                var pos = {
                    lat: lat,
                    lng: lng
                };
                console.log('lat: ' + pos.lat);
                console.log('lng: ' + pos.lng);
                return pos;
            }
            else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
        var coord = locate(address[i].toString());
        var lat = coord.lat;
        var lng = coord.lng
        console.log(lat);
    }
```

Comment: at which line of console.log are you facing this error?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is occurring at `var lat = coord.lat` in your `for` loop I imagine it is because you are trying to access `coord` before the callback of `geocode` has executed.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is cause by aynchronous.

> For a more general explanation of async behavior with different
>   examples, please see [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it
>   inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

you can do this to solve it.

```
function locate(val, callback) {
    console.log(val);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': val}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var pos = {
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
            };
            console.log('lat: ' + pos.lat);
            console.log('lng: ' + pos.lng);
            return pos;
        }
        else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            return null;
        }
    });
}

function mycallcack(coord)
{
        var lat = coord.lat;
        var lng = coord.lng
        console.log(lat);
}

for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
    locate(address[i].toString(), mycallback(coord));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue today, the problem being that the geocode method does not run synchronously, so has a callback function.  The return statement in the callback does not return back to the caller of your locate method.

The solution to this is to use promises.  If you are using jQuery then you can do...

```
function locate(val) {
    console.log(val);
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': val}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var pos = {
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
            };
            console.log('lat: ' + pos.lat);
            console.log('lng: ' + pos.lng);
            dfd.resolve(pos);
        }
        else {
            dfd.reject('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}

for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
    locate(address[i].toString())
      .then(function(coord) {;
        var lat = coord.lat;
        var lng = coord.lng;
        console.log(lat);
      })
      .catch(function(reason) {
        console.log(reason);
      });
}
```

Or in ES6:

```
function locate(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': val}, (results, status) => {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var pos = {
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
            };
            resolve(pos);
        }
        else {
            reject('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
    locate(address[i].toString())
      .then(coord => {;
        var lat = coord.lat;
        var lng = coord.lng;
        console.log(lat);
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
      });
}
```